# Segmentation fault at GTK+ program

Tags: c, gtk, segmentation-fault

I am trying to make an example of a simple **GTK+ viewer** using poppler and cairo which I found at [gtkforums.com](http://gtkforums.com) work. However I am getting a segmentation fault (I use **anjuta**).

When I use the debugger I get this:

**ID:1
File: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0
Line: 0
Function: ??
Address: 0x1d3f16 (dont think that matters anyway)**

terminal message while debugging:

> Debug Terminal for the process:
>   ------------------------------- &"warning: GDB: Failed to set controlling terminal: Operation not permitted\n"
>
> GLib-GObject-WARNING **: cannot register existing type `GdkWindow'
>
> GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_new: assertion `G_TYPE_IS_OBJECT
>   (object_type)' failed

Here is my code:

```
#include <config.h>
#include <glib/gi18n.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <glib.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <gdk/gdk.h>
#include <cairo.h>
#include <poppler.h>

/* gcc `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0 poppler-glib` -o pdfviewer pdfviewer.c */

static PopplerDocument* doc;
static PopplerPage* page;

static void
on_destroy(GtkWidget* w, gpointer data) {
    gtk_main_quit();
}

static gboolean
on_expose(GtkWidget* w, GdkEventExpose* e, gpointer data) {
    cairo_t* cr;
    cr = gdk_cairo_create(w->window);
    poppler_page_render(page, cr);
    cairo_destroy(cr);
    return FALSE;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    GtkWidget* win;
    GError* err = NULL;

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    doc = poppler_document_new_from_file("file:///home/user/test.pdf", NULL, &err);
    if (!doc) {
        printf("%s\n", err->message);
        g_object_unref(err);
        return 2;
    }

    page = poppler_document_get_page(doc, 0);
    if(!page) {
        printf("Could not open first page of document\n");
        g_object_unref(doc);
        return 3;
    }

    int pages = poppler_document_get_n_pages(doc);
    printf("There are %d pages in this pdf.\n", pages);

    win = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(win), "destroy",      G_CALLBACK(on_destroy), NULL);
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(win), "expose-event", G_CALLBACK(on_expose), NULL);
    gtk_widget_set_app_paintable(win, TRUE);
    gtk_widget_show_all(win);

    gtk_main();

    g_object_unref(page);
    g_object_unref(doc);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you go through with your debugger and tell us the line where the seg fault occurs??  From this code, there's a few places this could happen.

Comment: Make sure you build your program with debugging information enabled, so that the debugger can properly tell you where it's crashing.

Comment: i cant seem to find a way to copy all the debugger messages,but here's the error: error,msg="Cannot access memory at address 0x0"

Answer (score 1):

Based upon your comment it (*"Cannot access memory at address 0x0"*) appears that the program has a function that fails, but you didn't check the function's return value to ensure it is not `NULL` before using it.

Based purely on the code example above the first case of that would be if `gtk_window_new` failed; then the `g_signal_connect` and other functions cannot use the `win` value sensibly.

When I compiled the snippet, it compiled fine without warnings, and executed correctly. There was a poppler error message about the PDF document, but it wasn't relevant to your problems.

So your problem is likely either elsewhere (not within the included example) or a trivial mistake.

Comment: very strange that it works for you,here are my terminal errors when i try to run it and get the segmentation fault : GLib-GObject-WARNING **: cannot register existing type `GdkWindow'

GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_new: assertion `G_TYPE_IS_OBJECT (object_type)' failed

Answer (score 1):

One way to get more information is to set a breakpoint on g_log in the debugger and get a backtrace  of the warning / critical. With the backtrace you'll be able to see where exactly your code is calling the gtk+ function that is failing.

Comment: how can i do that in anjuta IDE?

Comment: Not sure how to do it in Anjuta, but in a command line gdb you'd write 'break g_log'.